# OptInt type function in Python

Tags: python

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

    mass=[]
    fall=[]
    year=[]

req = requests.get("https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json")
response =req.json()

for i in range(0,len(response)):
    mass.append(response[i]['mass']) 
    fall.append(response[i]['fall'])
    year.append(response[i]['year'])
```

I handle keyError with the help of Exception handling. If i got keyerror i added NAN value.
As java have function like OptString whenever we get keyerror it add default value.
I just want to get all data in list but via using optString type method.
Can you give any example ?

Thanks ,

Comment: Could you give an example input with the desired result?

Comment: Are you looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to provide a default value as the second argument.

For example:

```py
from math import nan

for obj in response:
    mass.append(obj.get('mass', nan))
    fall.append(obj.get('fall', nan))
    year.append(obj.get('year', nan))
```

Comment: Isn't the built-in `None` type good enough?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy The questions specifies "NAN", but it depends on the situation.

Comment: Yes that is the most `NaN` like value, but I would think `None` would be easiest to handle... Of course, you could also create a custom `NaN` value.